# SQL Server : changing uniqueidentifier into strings

Tags: sql-server, grafana

I'm working with a SQL Server database, I wanted to visualize a Dashboard with Grafana. All my data is `Uniqueidentifier`, and I wanted to ask how can I change that efficiently?

[image]

Currently I'm trying to use this:

```
CAST (columnname AS NVARCHAR(36)) AS [ComputerID]
```

If I want to use any kind of Graph in Grafana I need to set those into time series.

Comment: A column data type of `uniqueidentifier` and the T-SQL `CAST` expression in your question will not return the value depicted in the image. The value would be a string like `0EB8350D-599A-4D93-94EF-DB6397B849E4`. Is the actual column data type binary/varbinary?

Comment: SELECT TOP (1000) [ComputerID]
,[SoftwareID]
,[Installed]
,[LastSeen]
,[InstanzID]
,[InstallSource]
FROM [OEMS].[dbo].[oems_client_nn_software]

This is one of the colums

Comment: What does this query return? `SELECT t.name FROM OEMS.sys.types AS t JOIN OEMS.sys.columns AS c ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.oems_client_nn_software') AND c.name = N'ComputerID';`

Comment: @DanGuzman 
So i tryed it ,it returns " ComputerID]
      ,[SoftwareID]
      ,[Installed]
      ,[LastSeen]
      ,[InstanzID]
      ,[InstallSource] " all of those with data 
But in Grafana hes still missing and telling me " found no column named time" ...